# Monero Price Ticker

Tags: mobile

Who is behind [Monero Price Ticker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moneroticker.free) for Android?

What currencies are supported?

What permissions does the app require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already commented before, answers are on the Google Play store page you linked to, e.g.:

- Currencies: AUD, CHF, CNY, EUR, GBP, JPY, PLN, RUB

There's a contact e-mail address on the Google Play Store page: moneroticker@gmail.com.

I don't know what permissions it requires, I have no Android device at my disposal to test. Maybe get in touch with the author.